# Rendering Html.Partial in view with ServiceStack v4

Tags: razor, servicestack

I've updated project to use ServiceStack v4 (more specifically, v4.0.11) and having issues with rendering razor views; all content is rendered besides one in Html.Partial. What options do I have to solve this?

In .cshtml view:

```
<span>This is some brilliantly rendering span</span>
@Html.Raw(Model.SomeDataWhichRendersCorrectly)
@Html.Partial("PartialViewWhichIsNotRenderingIntoResultPage",Model)
```

Comment: Can you provide the failing code?

Comment: It's not the code, rendering just silently doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was in the following: you simply should "Copy always" all .cshtml files.